# Check list of dic and add values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

i have the following problem:

I have a list of dicts and want to loop through the list (**temp_list**) and check:

- if value **dic["z"]** of **temp[x]** and **temp[y]** is in between the range of **distance_value**.
- if not, insert a new dict in between **temp[x]** and **temp[y]** which contains a **z_value** of  ( **temp[y]-temp[x])/2** ), lets name it **dic_x_y**
- afterwards fill the left over values of the new inserted dic (**dic_x_y["t1"]**, **dic_x_y["angle1"]** and **dic_x_y["material"]**) with the values of the dic in **temp[x]**

Here is the data with the list and the variable:

```
    distance_value = 1000

    temp = [
    {
      "z": 1450,
      "t1": 0,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    },
    {
      "z": 1950,
      "t1": 25,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    },
    {
      "z": 12800,
      "t1": 25,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    },
    {
      "z": 13000,
      "t1": 15,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    },
    {
      "z": 25900,
      "t1": 15,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    },
    {
      "z": 26000,
      "t1": 10,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    }]
```

I searched a lot for my problem but could not find an answer. 
I hope i could state my problem clearly and someone can help me. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

i dont really know how to start but thats kind of my idea that i cannot get to work:

```
distance_value = 1000

for dic in temp: 
if "dic["z"] +1 (second element of the list) - dic["z"] < distance_value:
    new_dic = {"z": (dic["z"]+1 - dic["z"]), "t1": dic["t1"] , "angle1":dic["angle1"], "material":dic["material"] }
    temp.insert[dic["z"]+1, new_dic]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And that isn't the code it's just data.

Comment: Need Some clarity on the points. What is temp[x] and temp[y] and what is range of distance_value?.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but this is Stack Overflow you show us what you did and is not working and we can help solve it. WE don't solve your problems from scratch.

Comment: You should first process a simplified problem: you have a simple list  of numeric values (the "z" of your dictionnaries) and want to insert intermediary values when the distance between consecutive "z" is greater than range. When you can solve this, just add the dictionnaries to your solution. And please read [ask] because SO site has quality rules, and this question does not observe them...

Comment: In the first run temp[x] is supposses to be the first dic in the list ( temp[0] ) and temp[y] the second ( temp[1] ). In the second run it would be the second dic( temp[1]) and  the third (temp[2])  and so on

Comment: also shouldn't it be `temp[y] + temp[x] /2` so if you have 4000 and 5500 the middle is 4750 ? `

Comment: Yes of course, that was a typing mistake, i will correct it. I will post my code in a minute. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: I added my idea of code that i can not get to work. I hope someone can help me, i am sorry that i am new to all this.

Comment: will all the dictionaries in `temp` have the same `t1`, `angle1`, `material`?

Comment: sry i do not fully understand. Do you mean the keys or the values of the dictonary ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my **json** test file `test.json`:

```
[
    {
      "z": 1450,
      "t1": 0,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    },
    {
      "z": 1950,
      "t1": 25,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    },
    {
      "z": 12800,
      "t1": 25,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    },
    {
      "z": 13000,
      "t1": 15,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    },
    {
      "z": 25900,
      "t1": 15,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    },
    {
      "z": 26000,
      "t1": 10,
      "angle1": 90,
      "material": "Balsa 150"
    }]
```

The **python** code:

```
import json
with open('test.json') as f:
    temp = json.load(f)
distance_value = 1000

temp.sort(key=lambda k: k['z'])
counter = 0
Continue = True
while (Continue):
    for i in range (0,len(temp)-1):
        if(temp[i+1]['z'] - temp[i]['z'] > distance_value):
            Continue = True
            new_dic = {"z": (temp[i+1]['z'] + temp[i]['z'])/2., "t1": temp[i]['t1'], "angle1": 90, "material": temp[i]['material']}
            temp.append(new_dic)
            temp.sort(key=lambda k: k['z'])
            break
        else:
            Continue = False

temp_as_string = json.dumps(temp, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
print(temp_as_string)
```

my **output**:

```
[
    [
{
    "z": 1450,
    "t1": 0,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 1950,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 2628.125,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 3306.25,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 3984.375,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 4662.5,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 5340.625,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 6018.75,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 6696.875,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 7375.0,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 8053.125,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 8731.25,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 9409.375,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 10087.5,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 10765.625,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 11443.75,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 12121.875,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 12800,
    "t1": 25,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 13000,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 13806.25,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 14612.5,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 15418.75,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 16225.0,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 17031.25,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 17837.5,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 18643.75,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 19450.0,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 20256.25,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 21062.5,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 21868.75,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 22675.0,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 23481.25,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 24287.5,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 25093.75,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 25900,
    "t1": 15,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
},
{
    "z": 26000,
    "t1": 10,
    "angle1": 90,
    "material": "Balsa 150"
}
]
[Finished in 0.096s]
```

The logic is as follows:

1. Run a while loop with condition, *should I keep looping over my dictionaries and check?* **:** `Continue`
2. Inside the while loop, loop over the current list items, check if at any possible list[i+1]['z'] - list[i]['z'] is greater than set distance (this is the checking loop)
3. if found then make a new dict with middle point Z value, append, and re-sort (this is very important) and then break from for loop (break from checking loop at first occurrence), by breaking `Continue`condition for the while loop is still true
4. At a stage later on in the while loop when we go through all for loop and check condition not found, then `Continue` is false and the while loop breaks

Comment: It is close to what i need. The problem here is that the "t1" value is supposed to have the value of the dictonary before. So for example for all  "z" in between 1900 and 12800,  "t1" should have the value of 25 like in the dic where "z" is 1950.

Comment: i was able to implement a little change i your code and now i have what i needed. Thanks a lot Hadi

Comment: of course you can add any changes on your computer, I just gave hard coded values because they are all the same in the example you provided. But I was more focused on 'Z' values and the algorithm. If this works for you, you can implement it to suit your needs, cheers! Don't forget to check the answer if it's what you need.